# How can I make CCCrypt compute AES in another mode?

Tags: objective-c, cryptography, aes, commoncrypto, ctr-mode

The signature of one-shot crypto method `CCCrypt` is this (from `CommonCryptor.h`):

```
CCCryptorStatus CCCrypt(
    CCOperation op,         /* kCCEncrypt, etc. */
    CCAlgorithm alg,        /* kCCAlgorithmAES128, etc. */
    CCOptions options,      /* kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, etc. */
    const void *key,
    size_t keyLength,
    const void *iv,         /* optional initialization vector */
    const void *dataIn,     /* optional per op and alg */
    size_t dataInLength,
    void *dataOut,          /* data RETURNED here */
    size_t dataOutAvailable,
    size_t *dataOutMoved)
```

None of the parameter seems to accept a `CCMode` value (maybe sneakily, since all the enums are integers?). I have tried around combining it with the `CCOptions` parameter, but to no avail; the two enums are not options, and don't combine unambiguously.

It's not explicitly documented there, but I surmise from what I find around the web that the mode used with `kCCAlgorithmAES` is CBC.

How can I change the AES mode `CCCrypt` uses?

Comment: It's pretty easy to implement other modes if you have access to ECB or CBC. The only challenge is to correctly implement the counter which is encrypted for each block.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yea, no, I won't go around and implement crypto methods myself. That way only doom and madness lie.

Comment: @zaph - I expected to see you answer this one. Don't you have a crypto library based on Apple Common Crypto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> `CCCrypt`
>   Stateless, one-shot encrypt or decrypt operation.
>   This basically performs a sequence of `CCCrytorCreate()` [sic],
>   `CCCryptorUpdate()`, `CCCryptorFinal()`, and `CCCryptorRelease()`.

Now, `CCCryptorCreate` does not seem to accept a mode parameter, either; in fact, we [see](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60092.50.5/lib/CommonCryptor.c.auto.html) that CBC is indeed hardcoded (aside from the one, somewhat arbitrary that allows us to use ECB):

```
/* Determine mode from options - old call only supported ECB and CBC 
   we treat RC4 as a "mode" in that it's the only streaming cipher
   currently supported 
*/
if(alg == kCCAlgorithmRC4) mode = kCCModeRC4;
else if(options & kCCOptionECBMode) mode = kCCModeECB;
else mode = kCCModeCBC;
```

If we want to use another mode we have to use `CCCryptorCreateWithMode`. So, unfortunately, it does not appear to be possible to change the mode of `CCCrypt`.